# Выделяемая память для Java

Tags: java, jvm

Передаю в JVM command line parameters:

`-Xss512k -Xms1536m -Xmx2560m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF8`

Но логи говорят, что:

- Всего: 444мб,
- Свободной: 302мб,
- Используется: 142мб,

эти значения получаю через

````
   long freeMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1048576;
   long usedMemory = totalMemory - freeMemory;```
````

Comment: Версия JDK? При запуске какие предупреждения выдает?

Comment: Вы неверно используете ключи, правильный синтаксис типа: `-Xms:1536m` - ну и т.д.

Comment: поставил через двоеточие, получил ошибку

```Invalid initial heap size: -Xms:256m
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Process exited with code 1```

Comment: Ну а как вы хотели? Вы пытаетесь сбацать кучу слишком большого размера. У вас, судя по отчетам RAM 444м, а вы пытаетесь аллоцировать 256м... - самой ОСи ведь тоже где-то надо жить :)

Comment: jdk 8-ой версии

Comment: на виртуальной машине 4гб памяти, ОС может кушать 3.5 гб оперативы?)

Comment: `Всего: 444мб` - я об этом

Comment: в опенстеке какая-то магия творится, логи говорят что там памяти то 444, то 390, то 429. и притом рестарта программы не было (лог раз в час кидал инфу)